# How to shrink the size of a shared library?

Tags: android, c++, c, shared-libraries

I'm a Java programmer.
I included an open source C library, say A, into my android project to do some native work through function F1. Function F1 works well but the shared library compiled by A is, let's say, 5M in size. That means my final APK will increase about 5M which is big.
My question is, how can I shrink the shared library to only include functions that I need? Or at least remove most functions that I don't need? Is there any tools that can achieve this?

**Update 1:**
@Employed Russian has answered big part of the question above, which is by 'strip' tool.
My further question is, is there any tools can achieve things like what **ProGuard** does to Java, that is completely removing code I didn't call?

Answer (score 5):

> Function F1 works well but the shared library compiled by A is, let's say, 5M in size.

It is *exceedingly* likely that your shared library contains debug info, which can easily be 80% of the size, and which you don't actually need. Most open-source libraries build with `-O2 -g` flags, and the `-g` is what contributes to the size of the final library.

To get a library without debug info, you run `strip`, like so:

```
cp libA.so libA.so.orig # keep original in case you need to debug it later
strip -g libA.so
```

Now compare sizes of `libA.so` and `libA.so.orig`. Chances are, `libA.so` will be significantly smaller.

You should be able to squeeze `libA.so` even more, by running `strip libA.so`. This removes *all* symbols, not just debugging symbols, but makes it harder to debug any crashes related to `libA.so`. However, since you kept original full-debug copy, that shouldn't be a big problem.

Comment: It works great, 14.3M -> 7.4M after `strip -g`, 7.4M -> 5.7M after `strip`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Since you said the library is open source.. Just track the function implementation and along with classes it depends and recompile your own smaller version of the library.

Trust me this sound hard but will actually save you more time than playing with compiled c/c++ code.

Comment: It's my fault to say I just need one function F1. The truth is library A provides almost 100 functions and I need about 20.

Comment: Ha ha ha..  now that's a challenge... i suggest you find older versions of that library, they may be surprising small but provide the functions you need... as long as they were stable